# PSQL_HISTORY ignored by PyCharm

Tags: postgresql, pycharm

I have a Django project connecting to a PostgreSQL database which I develop in PyCharm, and I want to enable PostgreSQL history logging.

There is `PSQL_HISTORY` env variable set to `/home/user/apps/postgres/logs/.pycharm_log`, but when I start the project in PyCharm and update some data via the Django Admin (which certainly hits the database) -- nothing gets logged and the file is not created at all.

Is there a way to make PyCharm and `PSQL_HISTORY` work together as I expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'psql' is the name of a specific client tool.  Why would a completely different tool use psql's configuration options?  If you want to log every statement sent to the server, you could configure that in the server side with log_statement=all.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. I thought PyCharm uses psql from `PATH` under the hood...